# Freezed default value based on other fields

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I convert the following mode to freezed model ?

The issue is with `binaryIndex = binaryIndex ?? leftList.length -1;` Does freezed @Default support such feature ?

```
@JsonSerializable()
class MergeGroup {
  final List<String> merged;
  final List<String> leftList;
  final List<String> rightList;
  final int binaryIndex;

  MergeGroup({
    required this.merged,
    required this.leftList,
    required this.rightList,
    int? binaryIndex,
  }) : binaryIndex = binaryIndex ?? leftList.length -1;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MergeGroupToJson(this);

  factory MergeGroup.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MergeGroupFromJson(json);
}
```